# How to set (programatically) Gone Margin in Constraint Layout?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

There is a use case where `4` views are connected vertically (named "A","B","C","D" respectively from top to bottom).

```
            <include
                android:id="@+id/A"
                layout="@layout/search_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/dimen_16dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_title" />

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/B"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginHorizontal="12dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
                android:visibility="gone"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/A"
                tools:itemCount="3"
                tools:listitem="@layout/item_layout"
                tools:visibility="visible" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/C"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/dimen_0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/dimen_16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic"
                android:drawablePadding="@dimen/dimen_6dp"
                android:fontFamily="@string/font_family_roboto_regular"
                android:text="@string/pb_tag_error_note"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/B"
                tools:visibility="visible" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/D"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/dimen_0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_16dp"
                android:background="#11101010"
                android:fontFamily="@string/font_family_roboto_medium"
                android:paddingHorizontal="@dimen/dimen_16dp"
                android:paddingVertical="6dp"
                android:text="@string/text"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/C"
                app:layout_goneMarginTop="@dimen/dimen_12dp"
                tools:visibility="visible" />
```

When C is not visible then gone margin is set to `12dp` resulting in a height of `16dp` (`12dp` + `4dp` RV item margin) from "B". But when both "B" & "C" are gone then the gap between "A" & "D" is needed to be `24dp`.

The approach I'm using right now is programatically attaching D to the bottom of A & making margin as 24dp. Is there a way by which I can set gone margin top of D as 24dp when both B & C are gone?

Comment: Simply try Invisible

Comment: @gobu-csg I can't make it invisible as view height of C textview can be anything. (might not support the expected margins).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of a [Space](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Space) widget as follows:

- Place a space widget into the layout that is constrained to the parent start and the bottom of "A". The height of the widget will be `12dp`. Name this widget `space`.
- Create a [Barrier](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/Barrier) widget with a direction as `bottom` and the referenced ids as `space,C`.
- Constraint the top of "D" to the barrier.

You may need to make a few other adjustment.

The idea is that the *Space* widget will reserve `12dp` of space below "A" but not add anything that is visible. "D" will float up as widgets disappear with `12dp` margin until it hits the *Space*. At that point it will have `12dp` top margin plus the height of the *Space* (`12dp`) which is `24dp`.

Here is an example layout:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="16dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/A"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="A"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Space
        android:id="@+id/space"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="12dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/A" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/B"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="B"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/A" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/C"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/dimen_0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="C"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/B"
        app:layout_goneMarginTop="12dp" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier
        android:id="@+id/barrier"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:barrierAllowsGoneWidgets="true"
        app:barrierDirection="bottom"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="space,C" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/D"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/dimen_0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="D"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/barrier" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Hey @Cheticamp any benefit of using this approach than the one I proposed in my solution? Gone margin would have been a straightforward approach to this problem.

Comment: @VartulTripathi He provided simple solution.

Comment: I don't think that `gone` margins are going to do it for you unless you employ some coding as you do in your current solution. This solution is 100% XML which is what OPs are usually looking for when asking this sort of question.

Comment: If you just want to set a gone margin programmatically, take a look at [setGoneMargin()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintSet#setGoneMargin(int,%20int,%20int)).